# Apple Submission explanation

Tags: ios, applet, app-store, submission

[Apple IOS APP Submission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdWIo.png)

Can you explain what thats mean? what should I Choose? Yes or Now? what is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Export Compliance:

When your app using https, encryption algorithms, or crypto functionality in your application then you have to set `YES`.

If you need to answer as `YES` then you need to submit the annual self classification report to the BIS(Bureau of Industry and Security).

More information is available here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/complying_with_encryption_export_regulations

Advertise Identifier expalained here:

https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT205223